# Can't install jQuery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, wsh

I am trying to install the jQuery 1.11.3 installation from [this page](https://jquery.com/download/). When the download finishes and I click the file, I get this error:

[image]

I have tried this on three browsers: Google Chrome 44.0.2403.130 m, Internet Explorer 11, and Firefox 39, and each time I get the same error. I am running Windows 7. What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: there is nothing to install, you simply download the file (or save as) and include it as script tag in page.

Comment: if you have stable internet connection just use this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to run the JS file. It's not some kind of installation package. You just have move the file to your application, link the file to the page and use its functionality:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("...")
</script>
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, whoops! Thanks!